# Rsync: Transfer large number of files while ignoring directory structure

Tags: rsync

I am trying to copy files to a destination ignoring the directory structure. Here is how my files are stored:

```
/data/csv/1/history_1971-02-09.csv
/data/csv/1/history_1971-02-10.csv
/data/csv/2/history_1971-02-09.csv
/data/csv/2/history_1971-02-10.csv
...
```

I want to transfer all the .csv files in the same remote folder. The folder "csv" and all the subfolders can contain up to 1,000,000 files.

I am able to transfer and put all the csv files in the same remote folder with the command:

```
rsync -azvv --include-from=/tmp/transfer_list.txt --exclude=* /data/export/csv/*/ /tmp/rsync/
```

This works well for a limited number of files. The problem appears when there are 500,000+ files, it goes over each of the files to check the exclude pattern before transfering like this :

```
[sender] hiding file history_1971-02-09_18h40m33s.csv because of pattern *
[sender] hiding file history_-02-09_18h59m26s.csv because of pattern *
[sender] hiding file history_1971-02-09_18h56m23s.csv because of pattern *
....
```

Which takes forever to complete...

So my question is: Is there any way to do what im trying to do without using the "--exclude" option?

My limitations:

- I have to use rsync
- I have to transfer in batches of max 15,000 files (contained in the
  transfer_list.txt file)
- I cannot change the structure of the source folder
- I cannot store the data any other way because its a third party
  software